# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before

Tags: java, android

I'm using ContentProvider in my android application. But I'm getting this issue while calling methods.

```
09-22 11:40:11.054: E/AndroidRuntime(12589): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Comment: add code here.. to understand issue.

Comment: Add Source Code. We need it to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `cursor.moveToFirst();` , before you use it.
Also check if your cursor is not empty : `if (cursor.getCount())` ;One possible issue could be that you closed your cursor somewhere , and you try to access it ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have tracked some other flow from app because I'm using fragment and was creating new LoaderManager with same ID in each fragment, so that it cause this issue. But now I'm using same object of LoaderManager in all fragment and using different ID.